# Why is this function causing a crash? (Multilist)

Tags: c++, linked-list, crash

I'm working on my first multilist and it has been nothing but a nightmare so far. Right now, I am allowing the user to place the x,y spots (class_number,student_number) in on their own. My node looks like this:

```
    typedef struct node {
        int student_number;
        int class_number;
        struct node* classpointer;
        struct node* studentpointer;
    }* nodePtr;
```

Initialized with

```
List::List() {
    head = nullptr;
    currClass = nullptr;
    currStudent = nullptr;
}
```

To add in the data values and set up  pointers I have two functions.

```
void List::addNodeToClass() {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->classpointer = NULL;

    cout << "What class number would you like to add?" << endl;
        int x;
    cin >> x;
    n->class_number = x;

    if(head != NULL) {
        currClass = head;
        while (currClass->classpointer != NULL) {
            currClass = currClass->classpointer;
        }
        currClass->classpointer = n;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}
```

And

```
void List::addNodeToStudent() {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->studentpointer = NULL;

    cout << "What student number would you like to add?" << endl;
        int x;
    cin >> x;
    n->student_number = x;

    if(head != NULL) {
        currStudent = head;
        while (currStudent->studentpointer != NULL) {
            currStudent = currStudent->studentpointer;
        }
        currStudent->studentpointer = n;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}
```

I make function calls to both of these functions in my menu() function, and in main() I only call for menu()

```
int menu() {
    int input;
    List List;
    while (input != 3) {
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Press '1' to input a node" << endl;
        cout << "Press '2' to view the list of nodes" << endl;
        cout << "Press '3' to exit" << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 1) {
        List.addNodeToClass();
        List.addNodeToStudent();
        }
        else if (input == 2) {
        List.PrintList();
        }
        else if (input == 3) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
        cout <<"That is an invalid key" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program I am able to input the class node, then when I go to enter the student node, after hitting enter the program crashes. I know that there is a lot to look through, but I can't understand why it is. If someone would be able to tell me what I am doing wrong here I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You use the same `head` variable for two lists, is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: If I'm thinking about the logic correctly, a multilist should be like an x,y plane, with the head basically being "0,0" and one pointer should build the class list (x) and one building the student list (y)

Comment: By the way, do you have to make your own list? Why not simply use two [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), one for each "list"? And I put list inside quotation marks because you probably don't have to use a list, a vector might work just as well. Not that you even need two containers, just one should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `addNodeToClass` function never sets `node->studentpointer`. So when you follow that pointer in `addNodeToStudent`, you are dereferencing garbage.

Comment: So do I need to combine the two functions somehow?

Comment: It's hard to tell because it's not clear what your code is trying to do. Why do you have two pointers in the node? What is the list supposed to be a list of? Is it supposed to be two lists, one of students and one of classes? Or is supposed to be a list of (student,class) pairs? Currently, it's neither.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be safer with a default `node` constructor:

```
typedef struct node {
    node()
    {
        student_number = 0;
        class_number = 0;
        classpointer = nullptr;
        studentpointer = nullptr;
    }
    int student_number;
    int class_number;
    struct node* classpointer;
    struct node* studentpointer;
}* nodePtr;
```

And this would fix your issue because those attributes are not always initialized in your code (`new node` does not initialize the `node` attributes if there is no such constructor).

Comment: I believe that this fixed it... Let me redo my print function now and then if it's working correctly, then I love you and I will mark your answer as correct. <3

Comment: Actually, all you need to do is `new node()` (note the parentheses) instead of calling `new node;` and initializing each member.  The parens value initializes the members.